# Can't get back original numpy array after normalizing it for wirting to a .wav file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, audio, wav

I have used the write function from scipy.io.wavfile to generate a .wav file.

```
scaled = np.int16(lol/np.max(np.abs(lol))*32767)
write("my/path",44100,scaled)
```

Here I'm normalizing array name `lol` using above function. Now after writing this `.wav` file, When I read it in another code, it gives me the `scaled` array(Normalized `lol` array). But what I want is array `lol`, the original array which I've used previously to generate the sound file.

So I've **tried** writing inverse of the above function to get original `lol` array, but can't get any useful results. By writing inverse, I think it is impossible because the original function contains `np.max()` and `np.abs()`.

So how to get original array from this function?

Comment: What is `lol.dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) lists you can use 32-bit floating point data directly. This would not require any conversion after reading. A bit more information on the type of `lol` will help answer whether you need floating point or fixed point.